# Canvas кастомизация

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Делаю колесо фортуны и в основном вся информация по поводу него, это реализация с помощью `canvas`, но у меня колесо выглядит по другому. Возможно ли `canvas` отредактировать под такой вид?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H47Dz.png]

```js
const sectors = [
    { color: "#f82", label: "80" },
    { color: "#0bf", label: "10" },
    { color: "#fb0", label: "200" },
    { color: "#0fb", label: "50" },
    { color: "#b0f", label: "100" },
    { color: "#f0b", label: "5" },
    { color: "#bf0", label: "500" },
  ];

  const rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
  const tot = sectors.length;
  const EL_spin = document.querySelector("#spin");
  const ctx = document.querySelector("#wheel").getContext("2d");
  const dia = ctx.canvas.width;
  const rad = dia / 2;
  const PI = Math.PI;
  const TAU = 2 * PI;
  const arc = TAU / sectors.length;

  const friction = 0.991; // 0.995=soft, 0.99=mid, 0.98=hard
  let angVel = 0; // Angular velocity
  let ang = 0; // Angle in radians

  const getIndex = () => Math.floor(tot - (ang / TAU) * tot) % tot;
  function drawSector(sector, i) {
    const ang = arc * i;
    ctx.save();
    // COLOR
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = sector.color;
    ctx.moveTo(rad, rad);
    ctx.arc(rad, rad, rad, ang, ang + arc);
    ctx.lineTo(rad, rad);
    ctx.fill();
    // TEXT
    ctx.translate(rad, rad);
    ctx.rotate(ang + arc / 2);
    ctx.textAlign = "right";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.font = "bold 30px sans-serif";
    console.log(ctx);
    ctx.fillText(sector.label, rad - 10, 10);
    //
    ctx.restore();
  }

  function rotate() {
    const sector = sectors[getIndex()];
    ctx.canvas.style.transform = `rotate(${ang - PI / 2}rad)`;
    EL_spin.textContent = !angVel ? "SPIN" : sector.label;
    EL_spin.style.background = sector.color;
  }

  function finishedSpinning() {
    // Called when the wheel stops spinning
    const sector = sectors[getIndex()];
    alert(sector.label);
  }

  function frame() {
    if (!angVel) return;
    const isSpinning = angVel > 0; // Check if the wheel is currently spinning
    angVel *= friction; // Decrement velocity by friction
    if (angVel < 0.002) angVel = 0; // Bring to stop
    ang += angVel; // Update angle
    ang %= TAU; // Normalize angle
    rotate();

    if (isSpinning && angVel === 0) {
      // If the wheel was spinning, but isn't anymore, it has just stopped
      finishedSpinning();
    }
  }

  function engine() {
    frame();
    requestAnimationFrame(engine);
  }

  // INIT
  sectors.forEach(drawSector);
  rotate(); // Initial rotation
  engine(); // Start engine
  EL_spin.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!angVel) angVel = rand(0.25, 0.35);
  });
```

```css
  #wheelOfFortune {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #wheel {
    display: block;
  }

  #spin {
    font: 1.5em/0 sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: -15%;
    background: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px currentColor, 0 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.8s;
  }

  #spin::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: currentColor;
    border-top: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wheelOfFortune">
      <canvas id="wheel" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
      <div id="spin">SPIN</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: отредактировать что? Какой исходный вид? Как рисуется?

Comment: @Grundy Вставила код. Мне просто интересно, с помощью canvas, реально сделать такое как на скрине?

Comment: нарисовать можно любую картинку

Comment: все что тебе надо сделать - просто поменять функцию `drawSector`

Comment: @Grundy Что значит поменять? Настроить?

Comment: поменять - значит изменить код этой функции, чтобы вместо сектора рисовалась иконка